# How add event listener on dom element with redux-observable

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I need help to dispatch an action after a window keyup event

```
() => Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keyup').map(event => ({type: 'KEY_PRESSED', key: event.key, event}));
```

Thank u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you always want to be listening and dispatching actions on these `keyup` event, the Epic is pretty simple:

```
const windowKeyUpEpic = () =>
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keyup')
    .map(event => ({
      type: 'KEY_UP',
      key: event.key,
      event
    }));
```

But this is probably inefficient since you likely only want to be listening during some specific circumstance.

You can instead have some way to enable/disable this global listener:

```
const windowKeyUpEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('START_LISTEN_FOR_KEYUP')
    .switchMap(() =>
      Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keyup')
        .map(event => ({
          type: 'KEY_UP',
          key: event.key,
          event
        }))
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('STOP_LISTEN_FOR_KEYUP'))
    );
```

Comment: Why don't we use .switchMap(() => Observable.fromEvent(...)).map(...).takeUntil() ? If we put map inside switchMap(), I am concerned that putting more switchMap() calls (for e.g. a promise chain) would result in too much nesting.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal if you put them on the outside, you're applying those operators to the top-level stream--which means `takeUntil` will cancel the entire epic--you won't listen for future actions` and while the `map` wouldn't make a difference in this example, if you added error handling with `catch`, it would--you don't want the error to bubble outside the `switchMap` otherwise the error will reach the `action$.ofType` and the epic will terminate. This is sometimes called "isolating your observer chains"

Comment: Ok so we are doing this to make sure `action$.ofType` doesn't terminate. Does this mean it is okay to do what I suggested above inside the first `switchMap()`? For example:-
`action$.ofType(...).switchMap( () => Observable.fromPromise(...).switchMap( () => Observable.fromPromise(...)).switchMap(...).map(...).takeUntil(...))`

This would mean that I just need to do one level of nesting to isolate the observer chain.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal by it's nature I cannot say nesting one level is always the solution, but in your case if all you care about is not propagating the error to the top-level, then yep! It is true that in most redux-observable cases, one level isolation is prolly the norm but not always and definitely not the case for all RxJS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Observable.fromEvent is it not like Jquery event listener that is all the time listening . Does this not cause slower page ?

Comment: @jayphelps, can you plz share full working example of "Start/Stop event listening"?